# How to get those unique element in an array and collapse together?

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
animals = [
  {type: "dog", a: 2},
  {type: "dog", b: 7},
  {type: "dog", c: 2},
  {type: "cat", d: 3},
  {type: "cat", e: 4},
  {type: "cat", f: 0},
  {type: "rabbit", g: 0},
  {type: "rabbit", h: 1}
]
```

How to convert into

```
animals = [
  {type:"dog", a:2, b:7, c:2},
  {type:"cat", d:3, e:4, f:0},
  {type:"rabbit", g:0, h:1}
]
```

I don't know how to do it in a good way.
Using `each` and using `if` `else` statements to extract is too clumsy.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't have repeated keys in a hash, the best you can achieve is something like `animals = [ { dog: 1, age: [2, 7, 2] }, ...`.

Comment: Interesting enough his desired result structure evaluates in irb to => [{:dog=>1, :age=>2}, {:cat=>3, :age=>0}, {:rabbit=>5, :age=>1}]

Comment: @toro2k sorry for the mistake..i made those key unique now

Comment: What determines that the names `dog`, `cat`, `rabbit` are used for the grouping, and not `a`, `b`, or `c`?  Is it a hardcoded list?  The first entry in each Hash  (assumes using Ruby >=1.9)?

Comment: the value for the animal name for grouping , if dog:1, and dog:2 exists, then they will be 2 separate group

Comment: How do you know that `dog` is an animal name, and that `a` is not?  Do you have a list of valid animal names?  Note that Ruby may be smart, but not necessarily as smart as you :)

Comment: @PinnyM Thanks for you answer and question , i think i have made a mistake in the question, now i think my edit is more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do as below :

```
animals = [
  {type: "dog", a: 2},
  {type: "dog", b: 7},
  {type: "dog", c: 2},
  {type: "cat", d: 3},
  {type: "cat", e: 4},
  {type: "cat", f: 0},
  {type: "rabbit", g: 0},
  {type: "rabbit", h: 1}
]

array_of_merged_hash = animals.group_by do |inner_hash|
  inner_hash[:type]
end.map { |_,v| v.reduce(:merge) }

array_of_merged_hash
# => [{:type=>"dog", :a=>2, :b=>7, :c=>2},
#     {:type=>"cat", :d=>3, :e=>4, :f=>0},
#     {:type=>"rabbit", :g=>0, :h=>1}]
```

methods are : [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) .

Comment: Excellent and elegant solution!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is hard to think of such methods if i am not a experienced in ruby.